# how to upload zip file to the server using httpwebrequest in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am not able to upload zip file into server. While uploading this I am getting 500 internal server error.

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you give us more information about your issue and what's your code?

Answer (score 0):

BinaryReader can work:

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(file.FullName);
//long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

FileStream fStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

byte[] bdata = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);

br.Close();

fStream.Close();

// Write bdata to the HttpStream
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url-here");
// Additional webRequest parameters settings.
HttpStream stream = (Stream)webRequest.GetRequestStream();
stream .Write(bdata, 0, bdata.Length);
stream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebRewponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```